# JavaScript/Jquery - hide displayed div, show another, and repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I would like to show a div with id "houseImages" on page load while hiding divs "landImages", "renovationImages", "UpcomingImages", and "voteForNext".  Upon clicking "Landscaping", I would like to display the div "landImages" and hide div "houseImages".  Obviously, I would like this functionality to continue through the list and when I click "Painting" that div would reappear. How would I do this using JavaScript?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<Div id="mainContent">
            <h2> Our House </h2>
            <div id="columnLeft">
                <ul>
                    <li id="leftColumnPainting">
                        <a href="#houseImages">Painting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="leftColumnLandscaping">
                        <a href="landscaping.html">Landscaping</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="leftColumnRenovations">
                        <a href="renovations.html">Renovations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="leftColumnUpcoming">
                        <a href="upcoming.html">Upcoming</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="leftColumnNext">
                        <a href="whatsnext.html">Vote for <br>Next!</br></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="columnRight">
                <div id="title">
                <p> Over the course of a couple years we have done a number of projects around the house. Click on a link to your left to see the improvements! Don't forget to vote for what's next!
                </p>
                </div>
                <div id="houseImages">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/house1.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/house2.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/house3.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/house4.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="landImages">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/land1.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/land2.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/land3.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/land4.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="renovationImages">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/renovation1.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/renovation2.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/renovation3.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/renovation4.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="upcomingImages">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/upcoming1.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/upcoming2.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/upcoming3.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Painting.html"><img src="./img/renovation4.jpg" /></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="voteForNext">
                    <p> enter in voting form here</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into jQuery. It makes tasks like this really easy.

Comment: Very new to development so haven't tried much, how would I implement this using jquery?

Comment: someone answered below using jQuery, you can just include a `<script>` tag linking to jquery in your header. It's explained pretty well on http://www.jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your `<a href="">` to the ID of the div you would like to show. Then you can do something like:

```
$("#columnleft li a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("columnright div").hide();
   $("#"+$(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

Comment: so <a href="houseImages">Painting</painting> would be correct?

Comment: @James No. You change the `href` of the `<a>` in `<div id="columnright">`

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the Hide -> fadeIn effect combination.  If you have a 2 buttons a 2 divs, you can toggle which one is show like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="a">div 1</div>

<div id="b">div 2</div>
<button id="c">show div 1</button>
<button id="d">show div 2</button>​
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px;
    display: none;
}​
```

JS:

```
$('#c').click(function() {
    $('#b').hide();
    $('#a').fadeIn();
});
$('#d').click(function() {
    $('#a').hide();
    $('#b').fadeIn();
});​
```

See the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSNLN/

You attach this method to any event you can catch with jQuery, and show/hide and divs.

Comment: Could I use this method if I can clicking using hrefs?

Comment: yes, well kind of.  There is no need to use hrefs with this.  You can still use a `<a>` element, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSNLN/1/